# Managing Subscription Status of unsubs from in-flight journeys through Marketing cloud connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, unsubscriber, unsubscribe

I want to clarify on the methods that are available to manage unsubs of channel preference of contacts for journeys that are in-flight.

I am currently on Multi org ent 2.0 MC connect and using SF data source as entry into the journey and managing unsubs through a custom subscription page that is integrated with CRM. However, when a subscriber opts out of a journey that's in-flight, there's no way i can think of to suppress the subscriber from other emails within the journey.

Any advice or insights appreciated!

Comment: If the subscriber opts out in CRM, it'll get unsubscribed in SFMC as well (because of MC Connect) and will exit the journey automatically

Comment: Sure Maneesh, having the contact with the opt out status captured in crm is not an issue. The issue here is when a subscriber opts out through the custom unsub link from emails being sent while the contact is in the journey. How are you managing that when the unsub status is not part of Journey data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to configure journey exit criteria to check for the subscription status. These will be evaluated when contacts moves on from each wait step. Your object holding subscription status must of course be synced to SFMC, and connected in an attribute group. Please do observe, if you are using your consent/opt-in records in a one-to-many cardinality within data designer, [there are few things](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_data_relationships.htm&type=5) worth observing.